My integral solution $\frac{208}{3}$ differs from the book's $39$ why?
Solve the integral.
$$\int_{-1}^{3} (x+3)^2 \, dx$$
Integrating:
$\int_{-1}^{3} (x+3)^2 \, dx$
Let's expand and simplify
$(x+3)^2 = (x+3)(x+3) = x^2 + 3x + 3x + 9$
$= x^2 + 6x + 9$
Back to integration
$= \int_{-1}^{3} (x^2 + 6x + 9) \, dx$
$= \left[\frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{6x^2}{2} + 9x\right]_{-1}^{3}$
$= \left[\frac{x^3}{3} + 3x^2 + 9x\right]_{-1}^{3}$
Applying:
$F(3) = 63$, $F(-1) = -\frac{19}{3}$
$= 63 - (-\frac{19}{3})$
$=\frac{208}{3}$
My answer was wrong, according to the back of the book the correct solution is: $39$, but, how exactly?
Book:
Matematik från A till E Kurs D by Holmström, Martin
2nd Edition 2002. 320 sidor. Swedish. 

Mine is re-printed 2009, according to the entry page.

Ala ChatGPT

"The solution in your math book might be based on a different interpretation or simplification of the problem, but according to the standard method of integration, the correct result for the integral is $\frac{208}{3}$​, which does not equal 39.


If your math book states 39, you may want to verify whether there is a typographical error or another context provided (e.g., rounding or different limits of integration). However, the correct mathematical evaluation of this integral is $\frac{208}{3}$​, not 39."

All messy and confusing at the moment.

Back of the book is incorrect and you are correct, see here.

@SarveshRavichandranIyer Thanks. But, are you sure?

Yes I'm sure as well.

In fact, $\int_{-1}^{2} (x+3)^2 dx = 39$, so I wonder if the $2 \leftrightarrow 3$ is a typo in the book. Should be.

@SarveshRavichandranIyer I changed to, $2$ instead. The $F(3)=39$ and the $$F(-1)=-\frac{7}{3}$$ and thus, $$ F(3)-F(-1)=\frac{110}{3} \approx 36.66666667$$ your assumption is wrong.

he/she is correct

@ClaudeLeibovici prove it, because I don't see how. I tried what he suggested already and got a different answer.

@SaraJönsson If you change $3$ to $2$, you should have $F(2) - F(-1)$.

Make $x=t-3$ $$\int_{-1}^{2} (x+3)^2 dx = \int_{2}^5 t^2 dx = \frac{125}{3}-\frac{8}{3}=39$$

@SaraJönsson I'm not certain what you're doing. Note that we're integrating the same function, but with different limits. In particular, $F(-1)$ should stay the same, which you calculated to be -19/3 in the post.

@N.F.Taussig changed on a paper here. And got what I got. 36.6666667...

@ClaudeLeibovici I don't follow along on this, please explain more step by step for my .

Limits are likely -1 and 2, yielding 39 as the result.

Book:
Matematik från A till E Kurs D by Holmström, Martin
2nd Edition 2002. 320 sidor. Swedish. 

Mine is re-printed 2009, according to the entry page.
Correction
Upon checking the book again, the limit is $\left[-1,2\right]$. I must've blindly by mistake written 3 instead of 2. The book is actually correct.
$$\int_{-1}^{2} (x+3)^2 \, dx$$
Hence,
$= \left[\frac{x^3}{3} + 3x^2 + 9x\right]_{-1}^{2}$
Applying:
$F(2)=\frac{98}{3}$, $F(-1) = -\frac{19}{3}$
$=\frac{98}{3} + \frac{19}{3}$
$= 39$


"In particular, F(−1) should stay the same, which you calculated to be -19/3 in the post."

Most important comment by @Calvin Lin.
Thanks to:

@Sarvesh Ravichandran Iyer
@Claude Leibovici
@Calvin Lin
@dnqxt
@N. F. Taussig

